# Inline fancy box doesn't open at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, inline

i have a hidden DIV i want to open in fancybox when a link is pressed, but nothing happens i followed documentation and tried different other things but can't seem to open fancy box.
for the full code: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2354

```
<div id="quicklinks">

    <div class="ontwerp">
        <h1> Ontwerp </h1>

        <p> lorem ipsum </p>

        <a id="inline" class="ontwerpbutton" href="#data">ONTWERP</a>

        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="data" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("a#inline").fancybox({
                 'hideOnContentClick': false
            });
        </script>

   </div>
```

Comment: It's good to mention which version of Fancybox library is causing the issue in your question!

Comment: It is nothing wrong with this piece of code, make sure you are not hiding #data in some CSS or have any other interfering code

Comment: You actually are hiding the div #data inside another div with display:none

Comment: Try wrapping your fancybox initialization code inside the `.ready()` method